# Read spark csv with null value without converting to null from an API

Tags: api, apache-spark

We are using an API via spark to  copy an '.csv' file and convert it to '.txt' .

This is the body of the API

```
   {....
  "outputFileType" : "csv",
  "optionList":"delimiter=\t|header=false|emptyValue=null",
  "outputFolder": "XXXXX-{YYYY}-{MM}-{dd}-{HH}-{mm}-{ss}.txt",
  "targetFileShareName": "X",
   }
```

and this what i get as result :  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dHDj.png)

how can i get an empty values instead of null like this result [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfepl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I used this parametre "**nullValue=null**"  and it solved my probleme

```
 {....
  "outputFileType" : "csv",
  "optionList":"nullValue=null|delimiter=\t|header=false",
  "outputFolder": "XXXXX-{YYYY}-{MM}-{dd}-{HH}-{mm}-{ss}.txt",
  "targetFileShareName": "X",
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).